# Synchronized Profile and Environment

Tags: sync, user-profile, environment

So, I have a development machine at work, and a company laptop I take home. Both are running Ubuntu 14.04. (I can't upgrade for business software compatibility reasons.)

With my current set up, when working remotely, I have three options.

1. Maintain a separate environment on the laptop, using SCP to transfer files as needed.
2. SSH into the development machine, and do all my development through the command line.
3. Use a remote desktop tool, like xRDP. Unfortunately, with Ubuntu 14.04, I can't use Unity with xRDP. Also, this has a considerable amount of rendering lag which makes the

What I would like is something between a thin client and a roaming profile, where as soon as I log in (and connect to the VPN), it synchronizes my profile, applications, and settings. So any changes I make on my desktop are immediately reflected on the laptop (and vice versa).

Is there a good tool to accomplish this?

The only idea I have right now is to have a script on the laptop which runs on login/unlock to connect to the VPN and SCP all pertinent directories (/home/ApostleO, /opt/, etc.), then another script on logout/lock to SCP those directories back. I'd be afraid that I would miss something, or that there would be some incompatibility (with hardware differences, for instance) which I would not consider.

Any ideas?